# SU tag merge request: [microsoft-word] and [word]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Can these tags on Superuser be merged into [microsoft-word] ?

- [**[microsoft-word]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word): 358 tags
- [**[word]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word): 39 tags
- [**[msword]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msword): 1 tag

**EDIT:** Can a moderator, please, add "Status-completed" tag to this question? It seems that the tags were merged.

Comment: Thanks, Diago!...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[word] can refer to a lot of things, so I have picked out the questions where [word] is either not actually about Microsoft Word or .doc files, or it only mentions it as a tangent rather than having to deal with it.

- [Is there a Vim-like word processor?](https://superuser.com/questions/126421/is-there-a-vim-like-word-processor) (Word processing in general)
- [How to replace special characters (curly quotes, dashes, ellipses) in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/138798/how-to-replace-special-characters-curly-quotes-dashes-ellipses-in-osx) (Not Word-exclusive and the author is restricted from using MS Word, so it doesn't even make sense as a tag)
- https://superuser.com/questions/85904/software-for-creating-cheat-sheets (Tangentially mentioned, doesn't look applicable as a tag)

Everything else seems to have their merging papers in order. I suggest that someone retag those 3 separately, then call in the artillery to follow up on the remaining.

Comment: Thanks, Grace. I've retagged the above 3 questions properly, and the merging can be done now.